# Axon Framework: Aggregate Autowired Bean throws NullPointerException in Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, axon, axon-framework

Springboot and Axon: Basically I am unit testing an aggregate that uses three different ObjectMapper instances, each with a different configuration. These are defined in config class :

```
    @Configuration
    public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="flatMapper")
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper flatMapper(){
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Bean(name="unknownPropertiesMapper")
    public ObjectMapper unknownPropertiesMapper(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean(name="nullPropertiesMapper")
    public ObjectMapper nullPropertiesMapper(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

They are injected and used in my aggregate as follow:

```
@Aggregate
@Data
@Component
public class MyAggregate {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("flatMapper")
    private ObjectMapper flatMapper;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("unknownPropertiesMapper")
    private ObjectMapper unknownPropertiesMapper;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("nullPropertiesMapper")
    private ObjectMapper nullPropertiesMapper;


    @AggregateIdentifier
    private String id;

  //Methods and Handlers: a method is using "unknownPropertiesMapper" is "changedKeySet"
```

when I run SpringBootApplication everything is properly instanciated and working as expected, but when testing I get NullPointerException over thier instances:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = JacksonConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = OccurrenceAggregate.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = MyAggregate.class)
public class AggregateTest {
    
    private FixtureConfiguration<MyAggregate> fixture;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        fixture = new AggregateTestFixture<>(MyAggregate.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {

       fixture.givenNoPriorActivity().... 

    }
```

test console:

```
org.axonframework.test.AxonAssertionError: The command handler threw an unexpected exception

Expected <ANYTHING> but got <exception of type [NullPointerException]>. Stack trace follows:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.business.aggregates.MyAggregate.changedKeySet(MyAggregate.java:185)
```

`changedKeySet()` is throwing NPE because its using `unknownPropertiesMapper` and it is value is null.
as I mentionned it works fine when I run the Main class but not in tests (Junit5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Aggregate is not set up correctly. The correct way to inject a Spring Bean into the Aggregate is to add it to the CommandHandler method.

```
@CommandHandler
    public void handle(ACommand cmd, ObjectMapper flatMapper) {
```

In the test fixture you can inject it this way:

```
fixture.registerInjectableResource(flatMapper);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I shouldn't change the `handle` method signature, I am sure that this would work but not what I am looking for, I was more thinking of configuration "betise" that I miss or something like that...

Comment: You can try to register the resource with ```fixture.registerInjectableResource(flatMapper);```

Comment: I did just that still a null pointer exception on test run

Comment: Did you mock it?

Comment: I changed my code to what you suggested and it turned out that the ONLY way to do it, thanks!

Comment: @Yvonne Ceelie But it is not feasible, for example, when we are replaying events no command handler will be called and therefore the required dependencies will not be injected into the aggregate.

Comment: @Mr.Q you can also add the required dependency to event(sourcing) handlers.

Comment: @Yvonne Ceelie absolutely you can but I don't think that is a good idea. It is like thinking about dependencies before calling a method. I believe that this is a construction time concern and it should be somehow configurable in the aggregate constructors.

Comment: I agree that adding a dependency should be a conscious decision. You should always think if there is a better way to achieve the same thing (using the information of the events for instance). The event sourcing handlers are constructing the aggregate (when using the eventsourcing repository).